# How to Check Login Status?

Tags: android, post, authentication

I have to do login with my app.
After the login, if it is correct, I want to show a tabview with:

- My Stats
- Upload Photo
- MapView

This is my code for the login activity

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String url, user, pwd, user_field, pwd_field;

    url = "http://myurl.com/login/";

    user_field = "username";
    pwd_field = "password";
    user = "myuser";
    pwd = "mypass";

    List<NameValuePair> myList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    myList.add(new BasicNameValuePair(user_field, user)); 
    myList.add(new BasicNameValuePair(pwd_field, pwd));

    final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    final HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    //final HttpResponse end = null;
    //String endResult = null;

    Button login_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(myList));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    login_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                //HttpResponse end = response;
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: If my suggestion helped please let me know. Thanks

Comment: How can I keep the session and pass to the 3 tab activity?
I need to use cookie?
Or Android manage them automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Create a login.php script that you can call on the server and post your authentication to the script and let the script do your authentication and send a result back to your application.

So basically, your application will post the authentication to the login.php script and then the script will return to your application whether it was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to call the your login activity with "startActivityForResult" when your app starts the first time. You could use this skeleton and fill the blanks:

```
public class YourLoginActivity extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog executingDialog;
private Button loginButton;
private EditText username, password;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.login);

    loginButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.newTransaction.loginButton);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new LoginButtonListener());

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.login.username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.login.password);
}


private class LoginButtonListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {

        executingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", getString(R.string.message_executingLogin), true);

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {

                    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.getInstance();
                    Response response = httpClient.doLogin(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());

                    if(response.getCode() == 200){
                        // TODO: insert more checks, e.g. validating the answer here!
                        handler.post(loginDone);
                    }
                    else {
                        // TODO: handle error codes etc.
                        handler.post(loginFailed);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "", e);
                    handler.post(loginFailed);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}

private final Runnable loginDone = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        executingDialog.dismiss();
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
};

private final Runnable loginFailed = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        executingDialog.dismiss();
        // TODO: show error dialog
    }
};
```

I would suggest to implement a singleton wrapper around HttpClient. And if you intercept the startup with your login view, make sure you add the "[android:noHistory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)" attribute to it.